# Light Parenting Question

Tags: mesh, armature, lighting, parent, vertex-groups

I have been obsessing over this challenge for several hours now and feel it's time to reach out to my peers for assistance. Thank you in advance for your continued reading.

I am working on a robot with a blue lighted optics lens. My challenge is that I have not been able to figure out how to parent my light either to the robot head or the related bone so that the light maintains the same space as the optic lens when the robot head moves. Three photos showing the challenge.

[image: Robot with the lighted eye]

[image: The eye lighting disappears when the head moves]

[image: The point light will not move with the robot head or the associated bone]

My big question is how do I parent a light to a bone or other object so that it will move with it?

I have tried a hundred different approaches that have not worked. Suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Amir, Thank you but although I just learned a new trick or two this does not solve my challenge.

Comment: select the object, shift select the armature, switch to Pose mode, select the bone you want and Ctrl P (Parent to) > Bone

Comment: @fretbender "_this does not solve my challenge_" Why? We can't really help if you just say "it doesn't work". Why doesn't it solve, where does it fail?

Comment: Apologies @Duart if my message was lacking any real details. It was only my intent to say that the link provided was helpful but I still don't know how to fix my issue. Going back to my challenge let me ask this question. For lights or curves are there any settings that would affect parenting? On closer review of my project I realized that all the curve objects that I added to the robot ( tubes in the arms for example ) will not move with the armature as well. The pin lights and curves are behaving in the same manor. Thank you everyone again for your time. Much appreciated!!

Comment: @moonboots Nailed it, I have success !!! It is all about the order of operations. Thank you all for your help. I love this community.